# If Statements on python

Tags: python, if-statement, var

What is wrong with this?

```
passcode = 10

question = raw_input("type code ")

if question == passcode:
    print"yey"
```

Comment: You are trying to compare an `int` to a `str`. That's why. Cast your input to an `int` => `int(raw_input("type code "))`

Comment: That or make `passcode` a string (`passcode = '10'`). And the indentation looks wrong too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to compare the string `"10"` to the integer `10`. These aren't the same thing. You need to convert the string input to an int with `int()`. However, you need to be careful that the user only enters integers.

```
passcode = 10

question = raw_input("type code ")

if int(question) == passcode:
    print "yey"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for your problem ......

```
passcode = 10

question = raw_input("type code ")

if passcode == int(question):
    print"yey"
```

Comment: You are still creating the same problem.

Comment: thanks for confirming that I thought I was going loopy when that didn't work.